# Android: Background layout gets clicked when clicked on DrawerLayout sidebar

Tags: android

I created a DrawerLayout sidebar.  And when I click on the sidebar, the content in the background layout also gets clicked.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.clickBtn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And here is my layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!-- The main content view -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >  
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/clickBtn" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="hello pandora"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:text="hello world"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:background="#111"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

When I click button, the drawer slides open and in the 3rd picture, when I click on the sidebar, the button("hello pandora") in the background layer also gets clicked.
[image]

Is there anything i have to add in DrawerLayout to block the touch events in background layout??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed it myself, but in a bad way. I wrote an onClickListener for the navigation drawer layout (TextView here) and left it blank in onClick() method. This way it works now.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue.
Add `android:clickable="true"` in your layout.

Comment: Working........

Answer (score 0):

what you prominently call "the navigation drawer" there, is actually a `TextView` -

while it should rather be a `android.support.design.widget.NavigationView`,

with some `header.xml` and a `menu.xml` inflated, into which you have to put the child nodes.

a `DrawerLayout` without a `NavigationView` ..."might behave unexpectely".

on an Android, one can enable the option to "show layout boundaries", just alike in Android Studio there is a [Layout Inspector](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector), which both would have helped to understand the reason for abnormal behavior.